# String assignment difference

Tags: c++, string

What is the difference between `METHOD 1` and `METHOD 2`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // METHOD 1
    std::string name = "testing";
    std::string nameC = name;
    cout << "nameC is : " << nameC << endl;

    // METHOD 2
    char nameC1[8];
    const char* name1 = "testing";
    strlcpy(nameC1,name1,sizeof(nameC1));
    cout << "nameC1 is  : " << nameC1 << endl;
 }
```

Which is more efficient? Faster? When should one follow one over the other?

Comment: If you're programming in C++ then use C++ string unless you have a very good reason to use C strings, i.e. use method 1 not method 2.

Comment: Assigning strings this size is about nanoseconds. Why would we care if there is a speed difference?

Comment: char* is a frequent source of trouble (ofcourse, by programmers not as smart as you).

Answer (score 8):

### C++ way

```
std::string name = "testing";
std::string nameC = name;
```

In C++, resources are automatically handled. This is called [RAII](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Here, the string can be considered as a "value type", that is, something that, like an `int` or a `double`, can be safely copied, modified, returned, passed as a parameter, etc., without risk. *It just works*.

The RAII part means the string has an internal pointer to its content (i.e. "testing"). When you copy the string, the content is copied. When you exit the scope, the string is destroyed, automatically cleaning/deallocating the content. No memory leaks, here.

Optimizations exist, depending on implementations. For example, you could have [COW](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Copy-on-write), meaning the copy above would be similar to a pointer copy. In other cases, the string contains a small buffer, meaning small strings don't need heap allocation/deallocation.

Your mileage can vary, but the important points here are:

- RAII
- it just works

### C way

```
//METHOD 2**
char nameC1[8];
const char* name1 = "testing";
strlcpy(nameC1,name1,sizeof(nameC1));
```

In C, there are no such automated behaviors, so everything must be done by hand, and one modified line of code can break another without the compiler telling you.

In the current case above, as `nameC1` is an array on stack, you can't return it. This is quite a drawback, but in the other hand, it means no allocation on heap.

Another drawback of the C way is that you must use `strlcpy` because you don't want to have a buffer overrun (for example, if name1 was `"testingtestingtestingtesting"` instead of `"testing"`), so you must supply the size of the receiving string. Here, with the array, this is almost easy, as a `sizeof` will do the trick (but change the type from `char` to `wchar_t`, and the `sizeof` part will need to modified...)

But if the string type `nameC1` was changed to `char *` (because, for example, you want to return it from a function), then you would have to potentially (re)allocate its memory to have "testing" fit inside, meaning that you need to know the length of `name1` (which can be costly, and/or cumbersome), and then, not forget to deallocate it when not needing it anymore.

So:

- the code is brittle, as it depends on the types used. Change one thing, and the code is broken
- the code is limited, as you can't return an array declared on the stack
- the code is possibly broken, as your receiving buffer can't hold more than 7+1 characters

### Conclusion

The C code above is quite brittle.

Change one thing, and the others stop to work properly. For example, changing the array into a pointer will break the `strlcpy` because it relies on a `sizeof` (which, in case of a pointer, will return the wrong value).

And even as such, the code could be considered as broken by the end-user because you won't put more in the C array than 7 characters plus the `\0`, meaning the string will possibly be truncated.

Those problems don't exist in the C++ version of the code: The lines of C++ code will handle all and every cases, naturally.

So, the conclusion is that you should `std::string` as much as possible in your code, because it will automate things at zero or marginal cost.

And in the rare cases when you need faster processing (usually, you want to remove the heap allocation/deallocation parts), then you modify the code as needed (usually by allocating a fixed-size buffer, accepting its limitations in exchange of its strengths).

Comment: C++ spec doesn't allow COW for std::string.  COW would invalidate pointers and references to the string at the copy time.

Answer (score 3):

Use Method 1.

---

In the long run, `Method 1` is:

- Easier to use - you don't have to manually create clunky C-`string` implementations.
- More readable.
- **C++**.

---

`Method 2` is:

- Harder to use.
- Less readable.
- **C**.

---

As for the 'faster', either `Method` could be, depending on your implementation/etc. The minute *potential* difference doesn't really matter anyways, in the face of the other points listed above.

Comment: I would give this a +1 if you remove the faster/slower assertion - you can't know which is faster on any given platform/implementation, so it's an unfounded generalisation.

Answer (score 1):

Method1 is C++
Metthod2 is C

If you program is C++ (as indicated by the C++ tag of your question), use method 1: It helps code more easily string manipulations and allows for better flexibility  of objet lifetime. It will also allow for better interoperability with other C++ objects such as collections.